# In Elisp, how can I jump to the next org-heading, when the heading is folded?

Tags: org-mode

I only find org-next-visible-heading.

If I want to jump to the next sub heading, but the heading is folded, what function to run, then?;)

Comment: Do you want to leave it collapsed? So you end up on the ellipsis of the previous unfolded heading? What happens if there are multiple heading in the (folded) subtree? Going from one of the invisible headings to the next invisible heading would make no visible difference (unless you unfold). Or do you want it to unfold the heading before moving there? That's the kind of question you need to ask yourself *before* you post your question - and you should specify the behavior you want exactly.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was clear. Yes, I want to unfold it;)

Comment: So, unfold the current subtree (`org-fold-show-subtree`) and use `org-next-visible-heading`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this, silly willy

Thanks, NickD

```
(defun my/org-next-heading ()
   (interactive)
   (org-fold-show-subtree)
   (org-next-visible-heading 1)
   )
```